# how to select option using id with value to another select option value dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selector;  
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#DropDownList1').change(function() {

    // Hide all drop downs sharing the CSS class "toggledDropDown".
    $('.toggledDropDown').hide();

    // Build a selector for the selected drop down
    selector = ('#' + $(this).val());

    // Show the selected drop down
    $(selector).show();

 });

});

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(selector).change(function() {
     //var Link = $(selector).val();
   //$('#Submit').click(function() {
      //window.open(Link,'_blank');
     // alert(selector);
   var Link = (selector + $(this).val());

   window.open(Link,'_blank');
    
      alert(Link);
});
});


</script>
```

```css
.toggledDropDown
{
    display: none; /* Hiding the optional drop down lists */
}
```

```html
<div class="hrweb_box">
<ul>
<li><select id="DropDownList1" class="ctype">
  <option value=""> SELECT </option>
  <option value="1"> VISTO DE VISITANTE </option>
  <option value="2">INTERCAMBIO & TRAINEE </option>
  <option value="3">VISTO DE ESTUDANTE </option>
  <option value="4">GREEN CARD</option>
  <option value="5">VISTO DE TRABALHO</option>
  <option value="6">VISTO DE INVESTIMENTO</option>
</select></li>

<FORM name="f1"> 
<li>
<select id="1" name="menu4" class="toggledDropDown ctype">
    <option value="http://panavent.com/vistos-eua/"> VISTO B1 NEGOCIO </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-de-visitante-b2/">VISTO B2 TURISMO </option>
</select></li>

<li><select id="2" name="menu4" class="toggledDropDown ctype">
    <option value="http://panavent.com/1338-2/"> AU PAIR   </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/trainee/">TRAINEE</option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/intern-nos-eua/"> NTERN    </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/camp-counselor/">CAMP COUNSELOR </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/summer-camp-usa/"> SUMMER CAMP    </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/trabalho-de-verao/">SUMMER WORK</option>
</select></li>

<li><select id="3" name="menu4" class="toggledDropDown ctype">
    <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-do-estudantes/"> F-1 PARA CURSOS COMPLETOS    </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-m1/">M-1 PARA PROGRAMAS TECNICAS </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/estudante-segundario-eua/"> J-1 PARA ESTUDANTE SECUNDARIO     </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/estudantes-em-colegios-e-universidades/">J-1 PARA ESTUDANTE EM UNIVERSIDADES  </option> 
</select>​</li>


<li><select id="4" name="menu4" class="toggledDropDown ctype">
    <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-eb-1/"> EB-1 GREEN CARD   </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-eb-2/">EB-2 GREEN CARD </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-eb-3/"> EB-3 GREEN CARD    </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-eb-4/">EB-3 GREEN CARD  </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-eb-5/"> EB-5GREEN CARD    </option>
</select>​</li>

<li><select id="5" name="menu4" class="toggledDropDown ctype">
    <option value="http://panavent.com/391-2/"> H1B TRABALHO QUALIFICADO     </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/1324-2/">H2A TRABALHO EM AGRICULTURA </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-h2b/"> H2B  TRABALHO TEMPORARIO     </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-l-1-trabalho/">L1A TRANSFERENCIA INTRA COMPANY   </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-l-1b/"> L1B TRANSFERENCIA INTRA COMPANY    </option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/trabalho-de-verao/"> SUMMER WORK </option>
  
</select>​</li>

<li><select id="6" name="menu4" class="toggledDropDown ctype">
    <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-e2-investor/"> VISTO E-2 TRATADO</option>
  <option value="http://panavent.com/visto-eb-5/">VISTO EB-5 INVESTIMENTO</option>
</select></li>​
<li><input id="Submit" type="button" name="Submit" value="Go!">
</ul>
</div>
```

when you want to a option like  **green card**  then a another select option opened there are four choice then you select your choice and click to go (submit button) then i will goes according to link.

-- working---

1. when you select first option like above like green card this is working
2. I am confuse how to select option like green card -> after  there are four link anyone select then click button and location goes to according to link

please help  how to do this  I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - you did not close your `<form>` tag. Also, I changed your code around a bit to make it a bit more functional (if I understand what you were trying to do). Give it a go, hopefully it's what you are looking for.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewuyqnLo/2/)

```
$('.toggledDropDown').parent('li').hide();  //Hide sub-dropdown menus until initial dropdown is selected

//On change of initial select
$('#DropDownList1').change(function() {
  $('.toggledDropDown').parent('li').hide();    //Hide any open sub-dropdown menus
  var id = $(this).val();   //Get value from initial dropdown for sub-dropdown ID
  $('#' + id).parent('li').show();  //Show corresponding sub-dropdown menu
});

$('#Submit').click(function() {
  var link = $('#' + $('#DropDownList1').val()).val();
  window.open(link);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the button click event, get the value of the first select box, then use that to get the value of the corresponding select box. Then redirect the page with that value.

```
$('#Submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace($('#' + $('#DropDownList1').val()).val());
});
```